# NServiceBus default "stop" behavior

Tags: .net, nservicebus, behavior

Say my subscriber is processing a message in a handler and takes about 1 min or more to complete.

The subscribed is hosted in the NServiceBus.Host.exe process (version 2 or 3).

The subscriber IS fully transactional so that there are no external dependencies which would be left in bad state upon a breakdown.

Just after started handling the message, the service receives a stop signal (not abort or kill), due to a restart/upgrade or other.

Question:
What will happen:

A.
Will the service wait until the handler has completed its processing before stopping?

B.
Will the service abort whereby the message processing wil be interrupted and then rerun the message when the service is started again?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option B is whats is going to happen. We can't know how long to wait so we just shut the endpoint down.

Comment: Thank you very much Andreas. And thank you for a good tutorial at OreDev this year :).